# Android Studio WebView blank screen

Tags: java, android, html

When I try using WebView in Android Studio and insert the code needed to use it on my mobile device it only shows a white screen and never loads. I do this code by itself on its own Android Studio project and it loads but when I use it on a different android studio projects with lots more activities and layouts it doesn't work.

```
public class PrivateBrowser extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView w1; 
    WebSettings webSettings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_private_browser);

        w1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = w1.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        w1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        w1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
WebView w1;
WebSettings webSettings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_private_browser);

    w1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    final WebSettings webSettings = w1.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    w1.clearCache(true);

    w1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    w1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            w1.clearCache(true);
            w1.clearHistory();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code with the debugger?

Comment: I have nothing seems wrong. I created a new project with a web view and it worked but I guess when I add other activities and a web view after it doesn't as my point in my app is when you click a specific button it takes you to a web viewer and lets you search kind of like a private browser but the only issue is it doesn't load for me when I have lots of other activities but it does load when its on its own

Comment: Post your layout file.